# vertx.io java + twitter4j - event loop integration

Tags: java, twitter4j, vert.x, event-loop

I'm trying to integrate twitter4j with vertx event loop and I don't know if I'm doing it the right way.
I'm new to vertx, although I'm a Node.js developer, so I'm familiar with the event loop/single thread concept.

In my test, I want to subscribe to a twitter stream and publish the stream on the vertx event bus.

I've created an agnostic TwitterAPI class which will transform the twitter stream into an Observable (this will be hooked to vertx later):

```
public class TwitterAPI {
    public Observable<Status> getTwitterObservable() {
        return Observable.create(emitter -> {
            final TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory().getInstance();
            twitterStream.addListener(new StatusListener(){
                public void onStatus(Status status) {
                    emitter.onNext(status);
                }
                public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice) {}
                public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int numberOfLimitedStatuses) {}
                public void onException(Exception ex) {
                    emitter.onError(ex);
                }
                @Override
                public void onScrubGeo(long userId, long upToStatusId) {}

                @Override
                public void onStallWarning(StallWarning warning) {}
            });

            //twitterStream.filter("some keyword");
            twitterStream.sample();
        });
    }
}
```

Then I created a TwitterVerticle, which will listen to the above Observable and publish the stream on the event bus, so some other verticles can subscribe to it and process it:

```
public class TwitterVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
    public void start() {
        EventBus eb = this.vertx.eventBus();
        TwitterAPI twitterAPI = new TwitterAPI();
        twitterAPI.getTwitterObservable()
            .map(Status::getText)
            .filter(text -> text.startsWith("my keyword"))
            .subscribe(text -> {
                eb.publish("tweet-feed", text);
            });
    }
}
```

For example, I created another verticle which will listen to "twitter-feed" on event bus and publish it on WebSocket, so you can see the feed in the browser.

Everything is working well at the first look...but...my main question is: I'm not sure twitter4j will play well with the event loop, maybe my integration technique is wrong. Maybe I should make TwitterVerticle a Worker Verticle?

Could somebody take a look and let me know if this is the best way to accomplish such task?

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**

Publishing on event bus directly is a better pattern in this case?
Here is the modified code:

```
public class TwitterAPI {

    public void publishStreamOnEventBus(Vertx vertx) {
        EventBus eb = vertx.eventBus();
        TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory().getInstance();

        twitterStream.addListener(new StatusListener(){
            public void onStatus(Status status) {
                eb.publish("tweet-feed", status.getText());
            }
            public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice) {}
            public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int numberOfLimitedStatuses) {}
            public void onException(Exception ex) {
                //emitter.onError(ex);
            }
            @Override
            public void onScrubGeo(long userId, long upToStatusId) {}

            @Override
            public void onStallWarning(StallWarning warning) {}
        });

        twitterStream.sample();
    }
}



public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        new TwitterAPI().publishStreamOnEventBus(vertx);

        //vertx.deployVerticle(new TwitterVerticle()/*, new DeploymentOptions().setWorker(true)*/);
        vertx.deployVerticle(new WebServerVerticle());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First a couple of general recommendations.

1/ If subscribing to an `Observable` involves invoking blocking APIs, use a `blockingScheduler`:

```
Scheduler blockingScheduler = io.vertx.rx.java.RxHelper.blockingScheduler(vertx);
Observable<String> obs = twitterObservable.subscribeOn(blockingScheduler);
```

2/ Then I assume `twitter4j` uses its own threads to invoke the `StatusListener`, so the `EventBus#publish` call will be made on one of those. To come back to the verticle context use the `#observeOn` operator:

```
Scheduler contextScheduler = io.vertx.rx.java.RxHelper.scheduler(context);
Observable<String> obs = twitterObservable.observeOn(contextScheduler);
```

Combining the two changes:

```
public class TwitterVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
    public void start() {
        EventBus eb = this.vertx.eventBus();
        Scheduler contextScheduler = io.vertx.rx.java.RxHelper.scheduler(context);
        Scheduler blockingScheduler = io.vertx.rx.java.RxHelper.blockingScheduler(vertx);
        TwitterAPI twitterAPI = new TwitterAPI();
        twitterAPI.getTwitterObservable()
            .map(Status::getText)
            .filter(text -> text.startsWith("my keyword"))
            .observeOn(contextScheduler)
            .subscribeOn(blockingScheduler)
            .subscribe(text -> {
                eb.publish("tweet-feed", text);
            });
    }
}
```

All that said, if this the only job of the verticle, I would recommend to get rid of it and simply publish to the event bus. The event bus instance is thread safe and it's perfectly fine to invoke `publish` from the outside (non Vert.x) world. Actually, this is a good pattern to combine Vert.x code with legacy code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So you are saying I could send a reference of the Vertx instance and just publish on the instance's event bus from anywhere I need - I edited the initial question, maybe you can take a look...this is not production code, this is just a test to familiarize myself with Vertx.io. I'm starting a new project and I can't decide which technology to use, Node.js or Vertx/Java

Comment: @CatalinDima Deploying a verticle for a simple relay to event bus is not necessary. You can do it if it simplifies your packaging/deployment, but it's not necessary. Don't focus on this aspect, the important takeaway here is the importance of subscribeOn and observeOn